# Facebook login in react-native application for android

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-login

I want to add login with facebook functionality in my react-native application. I am making android application through react-native. I followed the steps from this link https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login/tree/master/android, I also referred this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk, but i got issues from both. The sample projects are also not running for android. Please suggest me step by step procedure for adding login with facebook functionality in my react-native application for android in a simpler way.

Comment: _The sample projects are also not running for android_. What is saying in message console?

Comment: No. I am using HelloFacebook project from this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/master/Sample/HelloFacebook. My build is getting failed with this error on console Cannot read packageName from /home/ajay/HelloFacebook/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml @Piyush

Comment: BTW I have got one idea to do that

Comment: Tell me how do I remove this error @Piyush

Comment: You need to create a new project and add _react-native-fbsdk_ for android as a module in your project. @Rashhh

Comment: I did this way too followed the article on facebook developers page got app id for the project and used it in my code..but got error through dat too @piyush

Comment: Using that what error are you getting? App Id mismatch or invalid hash key? @Rashhh

Comment: Build is getting failed through same error as I mentioned above. Please suggest me some solution. @Piyush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented the facebook login through https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk. The error I was facing due to my gradle sunchronization and 
I didn't add --> import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger; in MainApplication.java that was missing in the document. Do open your project in android studio to edit the android specific error as it becomes easy to trace them.